# making a while loop to output list of perfect squared numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to make a while loop that displays all possible perfect squared numbers up to the value is provided by the user input

Below is the code that I have produced for this however this only display the next possible perfect squared number

```
num = input("Type in a positive whole number: ")
count = 0
square = 0
while square <= num:
         count = count + 1
         square = count*count   
print square
```

Comment: indent `print square` so that it is inside the loop.

Comment: You seem to be a beginner. Python 2 is dead since the beginning of 2020. You should switch to Python 3. Now!

Comment: @TimurShtatland that worked thank you

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for letting me know this. I'm aware that there are newer versions of python I'm currently 2.7 as that is what is on my university asks us to use for our course

Comment: I wouldn't trust the qualification of that university. The death of Python 2 was announced over 10 years ago and they didn't manage to switch to Python 3? But OK, you as a student have no other choice.

Comment: @Matthias Tell me about it

Comment: @KevinMedjiako If that was not meant rhetorically: Read [PEP 373 -- Python 2.7 Release Schedule](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) from 3-Nov-2008. You can see there that end-of-life for Python 2 was originally planned for 2015 and then (since there was still a large code base) in April 2014 extended to 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3 syntax:
Convert input to `int` and use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
num = int(input("Type in a positive whole number: "))
print([i*i for i in range(int(num**0.5) + 1)])
```